# Recursively downloading a remote HTTP directory through java

Tags: java, http

I want to create a function to download a remote directory (Ex: `"https://server.net/production/current/"`) via HTTP to a local folder. I don't have control over the remote directory so I can't just create a convenient tar ball. I was able to find lots of questions related to retrieving individual files, but I couldn't find one that matched my use case.

To give you an idea of what I am referring to, here is a sample of what the directory looks like in browser.

[image: Example folder as seen in browser]

In other words I want to create a function equivalent to this `wget` where `Y` is the local destination folder and `X` is the remote directory to retrieve. I would call `wget` directly, but I want a cross-platform solution that will work on windows without additional setup.

```sh
wget -r -np -R "index.html*" -P Y X
```

The end goal is a java function like the one shown below.

```java
/**
 * Recursively downloads all of the files in a remote HTTPS directory to the local destination
 * folder.
 * @param remoteFolder a folder URL (Ex: "https://server.net/production/current/")
 * @param destination a local folder (Ex: "C:\Users\Home\project\production")
 */
public static void downloadDirectory(String remoteFolder, String destination) {}
```

**It can assume there are no circular dependencies in the remote directory and that the destination folder exists and is empty.**

Comment: You need to show actual code

Comment: I would, however I'm not sure how to approach the problem. I could manually parse the html page for the links and call the function recursively, but it seems likely that there is a better solution I have yet to encounter.

Comment: No. Roll up your sleeves.

Comment: What other solution would there be? The information you need resides inside the html. You need to parse it one way or another. How else would you get the names of the files and folders?

Comment: What you want to do is called "scraping." There is a lot of information out there on how to do it with various technology stacks. See for example https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+scraping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping there was some magic function or best practice in `java.io` or maybe Apache `commons-io` to do this, but since it sounds like none exists I wrote my own version that manually goes through the html page and follows links.

I'm just going to leave this answer here in case someone else has the same question or someone knows a way to improve my version.

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

private static final Pattern HREF_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");

/**
 * Recursively downloads all of the files in a remote HTTPS directory to a local
 * destination folder. This implementation requires that the destination string
 * ends in a file delimiter. If you don't know if it does, append "/" to the end
 * just to be safe.
 * 
 * @param src remote folder URL (Ex: "https://server.net/production/current/")
 * @param dst local folder to copy into (Ex: "C:\Users\Home\project\production\")
 */
public static void downloadDirectory(String src, String dst) throws IOException {
    Scanner out = new Scanner(new URL(src).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\n");
    List<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<>(8);

    while (out.hasNext()) {
        Matcher match = HREF_PATTERN.matcher(out.next());

        if (match.find())
            hrefs.add(match.group(1));
    }

    out.close();

    for (String next : hrefs) {
        if (next.equals("../"))
            continue;

        if (next.endsWith("/"))
            copyURLToDirectory(src + next, dst + next);
        else
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(src + next), new File(dst + next));
    }
}
```